# Percona connection fails after timeout

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, connection-timeout, percona

We have multimodule project with database, and sometimes we recieve this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT data FROM table]; No operations allowed after connection closed.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:79)
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor108.newInstance(Unknown Source)
... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 51,072,384 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 51,072,384 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor89.newInstance(Unknown Source)
... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
... 83 common frames omitted
```

Google suggested that it could be because of database closes connections when no queries in time specified in wait_timeout variable. 
So I reprodused this situation in that way:

Use Percona server 5.7.16, SpringBoot 1.3.3

Set timeouts in mysql to demonstrate problem (in production sets default value 8 hours):

```
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout = 15;
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 15;
```

Set heartbeat for mysql in springboot properties:

```
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
```

Run test:

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup("/....xml")
public void test() throws Exception {
    mockMvc
        .perform(get("/request_that_fetches_data_from_db"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    sleep(1000 * 60);
    mockMvc
         .perform(get("/request_that_fetches_data_from_db"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

Result is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server

at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
...

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 40 414 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2957)
... 46 more
```

I looked at mysql general log. There are query `SELECT 1` passes every 10 seconds, but when after that recieve business query, then straight recieve command `quit`. Error log was empty for testing period.

What is wrong and how to fix this problem without increasing wait_timeout?

P.S.`jdbc:mysql://url?autoReconnect=true` don't works too.

Comment: There is no good reason I can think of, to set the timeout so short.  I would suggest that what you need to do is fix whatever caused you to believe these short timeouts are necessary.  The timeouts are intended to be used by MySQL to sever abandoned connections. `SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS=2;` to increase the verbosity of the error log.

Comment: Thanks for answer! `SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS=2;` didn't add any additional records in the error log and general log.